# Cannot connect to ethernet internet

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, internet, ethernet

I cannot connect to the internet via ethernet cable, but I can connect via wifi. Also, my computer does not switch to ethernet. I can still see the wifi. How do I find the source of the problem and fix it?

Comment: change adapter settings in windows network settings. The realtek ethernet adapter was disabled. Enabled it and still no ethernet.

Comment: What's the other side of your ethernet cable connected to?

Comment: @ultrasawblade - computer ethernet port and another ethernet port. Why ?

Answer (score 1):

```
- What's the other side of your ethernet cable connected to?

- @LawrenceC - computer ethernet port and another ethernet port. Why ?
```

Sounds like you are in a campus or office environment.

If nothing else works when connected to that Ethernet port:

- The port in the wall may lead to a patch panel in your computer or telecom room which is not connected to any switch.
- It may lead to a switch that is powered off, faulty, or incorrectly configured.
- Some enterprise level switches have "port-security" that only allow a specific MAC or the first MAC detected to communicate on the network.  There won't be a way for you to find that MAC out from the port.
- There may be issues with the cable in the wall
- There may not in fact be a cable in the wall leading anywhere

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I work in the kind of environment which you described. Yesterday, I connected to the same port using another ethernet cable. It was working. Now, I am using a different one. Its unlikely that the wall port is not working.

Comment: btw, what made you guess its a campus or work environment ?

Comment: Few households have Ethernet ports in the wall, though some newer apartments might.

Comment: might be your new cable is a crossover cable.  don't use those.

Comment: You changed your name, ultrasawblade. How come?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_identity_management - ;)